# How do I query Last Logon Date via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to query machines which were last logged on to 30 days ago

```bsh
Clear-Host

$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$NotInUse = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Where {
    $_.name -Like "*LN-T48*" -and $_.LastLogonDate -gt $Threshold
}

$NotInUse | select Name, LastLogonDate -Verbose
```

Comment: The results i'm getting seems to be a few days ago and not -30 days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -lt

Using the filter is quicker:

```
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$NotInUse = Get-ADComputer -Filter  {LastLogonDate -lt $Threshold} -Properties LastLogonDate |
 Where { $_.name -Like "*LN-T48*"}

 $NotInUse | select Name, LastLogonDate -Verbose | sort LastLogonDate
```